# Access data blank in report

Tags: vba, ms-access, report, ms-access-forms

I have been away from Access for a while and I needed to create a simple data entry form that saves the data to a table and prints the data in a report.  I am sure it it something simple, but I cannot get the data to show up in the report.

Here is part of the form filled in with test data:

[image]

Here is part of the table showing the data was entered/saved:

[image]

Here is the report that displays, I have set the print button in the form to display report in print preview:

[image]

Here is the Event Procedure for the print button:

```
Private Sub PrntBtn_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenReport "NCR_rpt", acViewPreview, , _"[NCR_Number]=Forms!NCR_form"
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing a form control to the `where` condition argument of the `openreport` method:

```
"[NCR_Number]=Forms!NCR_form"
```

This should instead reference the form control containing the `NCR_Number` field, e.g.:

```
Private Sub PrntBtn_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenReport "NCR_rpt", acViewPreview, , "[NCR_Number]=Forms!NCR_form!NCR_Number"
End Sub
```